# D lang - Pass by ref class into class method

Tags: d

How do I pass a class into another class method? Using this example "animal.name" will be empty in the eat method.

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    Animal cat = new Animal;
    Animal dog = new Animal;

    cat.name = "fluffy";
    dog.name = "bruce";

    dog.eat(cat);
}

class Animal
{
    auto name = "none";

    void eat( Animal animal )
    {
        writeln(this.name);
        writeln("is going to eat");
        writeln(animal.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `auto name;` will compile, nor `'fluffy'`.

Comment: It still won't compile, single quotes can't be used to delimit strings. (backticks can, not single quotes though)

Comment: @OrvidKing - thanks i updated it. obviously this is not the code I'm working with, but merely an example.

Comment: Why doesn't the code you posted here work? It looks correct to me (minor syntax problems excepted)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, running the example works so it must  be another (not related to my original question) issue with the actual code I'm working with.

For anyone coming to this question in the future, this compiles and works:

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    Cat cat = new Cat;
    Dog dog = new Dog;

    cat.name = "fluffy";
    dog.name = "bruce";

    dog.eat(cat);
}

class Animal
{
    auto name = "none";

    void eat( Animal animal )
    {
        writeln(this.name);
        writeln("is going to eat");
        writeln(animal.name);
    }
}

class Cat: Animal
{

}

class Dog: Animal
{

}
```

Comment: It does compile and work, but it is not a good practice to allow direct access to your class members if you really, really do not have to do it... Instead, use the constructor, and give the name of an Animal in the constructor. Here is DPaste link for this D code: http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/5abdc4a5